# Delete an element in array of a structure in swift

Tags: swift

EDIT: 
I would like to delete one of the element in the array list of structure type

```
struct Folder {
  let name:String
  let menu:[String:String]
}
```

I have a variable  of

```
section = Folder
```

I want to check that is there any value in menu[String:String] contain specific value or not and remove that element out

```
section.menu = ["hello" : "a","b","c"]
if there any value of hello == a {
    remove it out
}
```

At the end

```
section.menu = ["hello" : "b","c"]
```

Comment: `sections.removeAll(where: { $0.name == "hello" })`?

Comment: sorry I ask in wrong question, I just edited it can you please check it again?

Comment: "remove that dictionary out from the section.menu": Being remove the key hello and its associated value?

Comment: Also, there is no array, just a dictionary. => `var folder = Folder(name: "Name", menu: ["Hello": "Hello Value", "Other Key": "Other Value"])
print(folder); folder.menu["Hello"] = nil; print(folder)`

Comment: I misunderstand about it, Is it possible to delete the value of "Hello" if it is = "Hello Value"  (just delete the "Hello Value") and keep other thin remain the same

Comment: I've updated my answer after your edit

Answer (score 0):

So first of all you need to make `menu` an actual variable instead of a constant, and it needs to be a dictionary of Strings to Array of Strings.

Then, you can remove entries from the array easily by getting their index and calling `remove`:

```
struct Folder {
    let name:String
    var menu: [String: [String]]
}

var section = Folder(name: "foo", menu: [ "hello": ["a", "b", "c"]])

if let index = section.menu["hello"]?.firstIndex(of: "a") {
    section.menu["hello"]?.remove(at: index)
}

print(section.menu) // ["hello": ["b", "c"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create `mutating` function like that `removeMenu(forValue value: String)`

```
struct Folder {
    let name:String
    var menu:[String:String]

    mutating func removeMenu(forValue value: String) {
        menu = menu.filter({ $0.value != value})
    }
}

var section = Folder(name: "FolderName", menu: ["k1": "keyValue1", "k2": "keyValue2"])

section.removeMenu(forValue: "keyValue1")

print(section)
```

output:

```
//Folder(name: "FolderName", menu: ["k2": "keyValue2"])
```